# "You have" or "You've got" a message?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I know it's common to say "You've got a message" and I'm wondering whether it's also correct to say "You have a message"?

Comment: As AOL taught us many years ago, the phrase is "You've got mail!"

Comment: Why the down vote? Is the question not valid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends, whether you want to say if somebody has (owns) a message right now or if somebody has got (received) a message.

Comment: That's not correct. "You've got a message" can mean exactly the same thing as "You have a message." (Likewise, "He's got blue eyes" means "He has blue eyes," not "He has received blue eyes.")